# Ignoring hidden files with regular expressions in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to read every file in a specified directory. I'd like to ignore hidden files. I've found a way to do this, but I'm pretty sure it is the most inefficient way to do this.

This is what I've tried,

```
Find.find(directory) do |path|
     file_paths << path if path =~ /.*\./ and !path.split("/")[-1].to_s.starts_with?(".")
end
```

This works. But I hate it.

I then tried to do this,

```
file_paths << path if path =~ /.*\./ and path =~ /^\./
```

But this returned nothing for me. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: By "hidden files", do you actually mean "files that begin with '.'"? On some platforms, "hidden" is an attribute of the file.

Comment: Yes. But don't all hidden files start with a "."? Even the ones with hidden as an attribute?

Comment: No, not all. Not on Windows, for example.

Comment: @SwaathiK no hidden files on Windows for instance can have any name or extension. They simply have an attribute hidden. Also files starting with a `.` are not always hidden e.g. `.gitignore`, `.gemspec`, `.rspec`, etc.

Comment: @SwaathiK - based on everyones comments, do you want to ignore file dot files instead?

Comment: This is what is commonly referred to as an "[X-Y  question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): you ask how to use a regex to achieve a certain desired outcome, when you really just want to to know how to best obtain that outcome. As @engineersmnky shows, it does not involve a regex.

Comment: I am actually confused. If not all .files are hidden files then how do I even know if a file is hidden?

Answer (score 6):

You could just use `Dir`

```
file_paths = Dir.glob("#{directory}/*")
```

`Dir#glob` Docs:

> Returns the filenames found by expanding pattern which is an Array of the patterns or the pattern String, either as an array or as parameters to the block.
>
> > Note, this will not match Unix-like hidden files (dotfiles). In order to include those in the match results, you must use something like “{*,.*}”.

per @arco444 if you want this to search recursively

```
file_paths = Dir.glob("#{directory}/**/*")
```

Comment: `glob` looks good, but I think `Dir.glob(File.join(directory, '**', '*'))` would be the equivalent to `Find.find(directory)` (without the dotfiles)

Comment: The more important sentence from the docs is probably *"Note, this [`*`] will not match Unix-like hidden files (dotfiles)"*

Comment: @arco444 I've addressed this in my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987394/ignoring-hidden-files-with-regular-expressions-in-ruby#comment46225000_28988069): `dir/**/*` will match all files recursively (excluding dotfiles).

Comment: @Stefan you are correct copied the wrong text. Editted

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to ignore files starting with `.`, the below would append those that don't to the `file_paths` array

```
Find.find(directory) do |path|
    if File.file?(path)
        file_paths << path unless File.basename(path).start_with?(".")
    end
end
```

Note that this will not necessarily ignore *hidden* files, for the reasons mentioned in the comments. It also currently includes "hidden" directories, i.e. a file such as `/some/.hidden/directory/normal.file` would be included in the list.